# Android Realm 4.3.1 Cannot change Gradle plugin version

Tags: android, gradle, realm

I use Realm 4.3.1. I found a question that is my Gradle plugin version auto updated. But my Gradle plugin version setting is 3.0.1 and when I build the project AndroidStudio tells me it is using Gradle plugin 3.1.0-Alpha3, ignoring my build tool version 25.0.3, as shown below.

[image]

So I removed Realm 4.3.1, and my Gradle plugin 3.0.1 works - this is my project build.gradle

[image]

Comment: what is your target sdk version?

Comment: 26,I mean it likes Realm changed my Gradle plugin version

Comment: are you downgrade or upgrade gradle version?

Comment: i'm tring to downgrade gradle version ,but it not works.Always 3.1.0-Alpha03

Comment: But what is the question?

Comment: This was fixed in 4.3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug in 4.3.0 because of some trickiness with the maven publish plugin on the Realm side.

It was fixed in 4.3.2.

> 4.3.2 (2018-01-17)
>
> Bug Fixes
>
> Prevent Realms Gradle plugin from transitively forcing specific versions of Google Build Tools onto downstream projects (#5640).

Comment: Thank u very much